# Setting default index variable to URL

Tags: php, html, url

i want to set my index with variable..like example `localhost/sitename` i want it to be `localhost/sitename/index.php?variable=value` ^^ anyone could help

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  Are you looking for some kind of URL rewriting advice?  If so, you should specifically indicate what your URL currently looks like and what you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an .htaccess file in your webroot directory, and then inside put:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Remove the middle 2 lines if you don't want direct access to valid directories/files.

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm getting it. is .htaccess is an already made file or i should create it?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then you would have to create it.

Comment: what if i only want to change one of my sites, like i have site1 and site2, and i only want to put index variable to site1, will this change also affect site2?

Comment: htaccess will affect only the folder in which you keep it. if you put htaccess file in site1's folder, then that's it. nothing else is affected

Comment: added more help for directly filtering out certain folders